# Colouring bars of histogram depending on column value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following code working for displaying a histogram of the number of crimes **of a particular type** (e.g. narcotics, battery etc.) for a given area in Chicago.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["ward", "count", "primary_type"])

for name, group in groups:

  df = df.append({
                  "ward" : name,
                  "count": group['Primary Type'].value_counts().nlargest(n=1)[0],
                  "primary_type":(group['Primary Type'].value_counts().nlargest(n=1).keys()[0]
                                  )}, ignore_index=True)



df = df.set_index("ward")

ax = df.plot.bar(rot=0, width=0.75, figsize=(10, 5))
ax.set_xlabel('', fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel('Incidents', fontsize=16)
```

[image]

What I'd like to do is colour the bars of the histogram a particular colour depending on their `primary_type` value.

```
      count primary_type
ward                    
1.0    9920        THEFT
2.0   18439        THEFT
3.0    7822      BATTERY
4.0    6959        THEFT
5.0    6535      BATTERY
6.0    9294      BATTERY
7.0    8480      BATTERY
8.0    8066      BATTERY
9.0    7847      BATTERY
10.0   4831      BATTERY
```

Comment: Without any sample data it is difficult to help but `df.plot()` has a param called `colormap` that you can use in conjunction with `matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap`

Comment: @Yo_Chris Should have included that earlier, thanks. I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming df  =

```
    ward    count   primary_type
1   1.0     9920    THEFT
2   2.0    18439    THEFT
3   3.0    7822     BATTERY
4   4.0    6959     THEFT
.
.
```

then you can group them based on 'primart type' and plot bars for each group like shown below.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for group_name, group in df.groupby('primary_type'):
    ax.bar(x = group['ward'], height = group['count'], label = group_name)
plt.legend()
```

results in

[image]

Comment: Glad to help. If this answers your question, please mark it as 'Accepted' Thanks.